# What is a Round Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series inaugurated by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with his original [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

If a word adheres to a certain rule, then I call it a Round Word™.

Use the examples below to find the rule.

| Round Words™ | Not Round Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| TEEN | TEXT |
| BUTTON | TENNIS |
| RADIO | CANOE |
| WEIRD | NORMAL |
| MORAL | POWER |
| BASSOON | WOODWIND |
| BATON | BETWEEN |
| NEUTRON | PROTON |
| PHYSICS | POETRY |
| MATH | SCIENCE |
| DEMOTE | CENSURE |
| BAROMETRIC | GEODESIC |
| BEGIN | FINISH |
| TOLD | SAID |
| CAT | DOG |

In case you want it in CSV:

```
Round Words™, Not Round Words™
TEEN, TEXT
BUTTON, TENNIS
RADIO, CANOE
WEIRD, NORMAL
MORAL, POWER
BASSOON, WOODWIND
BATON, BETWEEN
NEUTRON, PROTON
PHYSICS, POETRY
MATH, SCIENCE
DEMOTE, CENSURE
BAROMETRIC, GEODESIC
BEGIN, FINISH
TOLD, SAID
CAT, DOG
```

The puzzle relies on the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Round Word™ or not on its own.

**Clarification** (Also a bit of a hint, hence the spoiler format.  I went back and forth as to whether you needed to know this):

> Most words (including all of the clue words) are definitively Round or Not Round. However, there are some words which could be either, based on the clue words.  I call these words Oblong Words™.  Your definition of Round might differ slightly from someone else's in whether or not it includes Oblong Words™.  Either way is acceptable (as long as it's consistent).

A small hint based on the above:

> Here are three Oblong Words™: RAGTAG, VINYL, DERAIL

Comment: I have been looking at more of these, and it seems customary to have most if not all of the words be related to the corresponding one in the opposite column.  I did this with some of my pairs, but in some cases, I chose a conceptually unrelated word with similar properties (like radio/canoe are both consonant, vowel, consonant, vowel, vowel).  I am considering changing my list to make it more like the others.  Should I do this or leave it as is?

Comment: Both types of pairings - even intermingled - are common. I think the lists are fine as they stand.  Whether the relation is by meaning or by word composition still maintains a sense of symmetry that is satisfying.   Having said that, even a completely random assortment of words is fine and in some cases may be necessary; that doesn't necessarily detract from the puzzle, unless it's clear the puzzle setter just couldn't be bothered.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with this format to know whether the information I put under the spoiler tag is necessary or not.  I appreciate any input from veterans in that regard.

Comment: I am sensing... This might again be related to QWERTY? May be I am bad with geometry but some of these make my fingers create a circular kind of path on the keyboard.

Comment: @Techidiot is that a request for a hint (i.e. warm/cold) or just a musing?

Comment: No just thinking. It's okay if you are not ready to add the hint yet.

Comment: Alright.  I will say, though (unhelpfully) that I wrote this puzzle before I saw the (other?) QWERTY-related ones.

Comment: More helpfully, I'm adding a smallish (I think) hint to the post.  Not even a hint really, just some more words, though they will be at the bottom under spoiler cover, for reasons that the currently spoiler-covered section makes clear.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A round word is a word such that:

> If you put all letters of the alphabet on a circle, with alphabetic order and equidistance separation (on a regular 26-gone), the letters of a round word follow a path that is always clockwise (or anticlockwise) if you choose the shortest path between consecutive letters.
>  For example, if you put all the letters clockwise, then RADIO is a clockwise round word, but BUTTON is an anticlockwise round word.

An oblong word is a word which:

> contains consecutive letters that are 13 spaces apart in the circle (i.e. ROT-13 conjugates) and so there are two shortest parts between the points and one of them allow the sequence to be always clockwise (or anticlockwise).

Comment: You should probably explain what makes words Oblong, too...